# Why .class_name:nth-child(even) counts elements without .class_name

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

What is the rule counting with `:nth-child()`? Is it simply a bug?

```css
.info_row:nth-child(even) {
  background: orange
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <div class="info_row">
    <div>Category:</div>
    <div>data</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I wrap `div.info_row` in other `<div>` or delete `<h2>` it is obvious, that `.info_row:nth-child(even)` is being counted with `<h2>` without `.info_row` class.

Comment: its select the whole info_row-div, so everything is orange youre missing a space `.info_row :nth-child(even)`

Comment: Pseudo-classes like `nth-child` match elements, not classes of elements. Adding a class makes it act like a filter and it becomes more restrictive. Plus, the actual selector is applied to the `.info_row` element, not it's children.

Comment: This might help https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: What if I want every even .info_row not its children to be affected by the rule?

Comment: Why this works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/Zydnar/xuoxe6mj/1/

Comment: @Zydnar Because it is highlighting the info_row that is an even-child of info_row's parent. `nth-child` has more complex rules than you are realizing.

Comment: @TylerH but in the fiddle in the link the parent has no class so I can't understand "the info_row that is an even-child of info_row's parent", do you?

Comment: `nth-child` doesn't care about classes. It cares about children. You adding a class like `.info_row:nth-child(2)` just restricts how many times it will *match* your elements. The logic behind how `nth-child(2)` works doesn't change just because you threw a class in front of it. `.info_row:nth-child(2)` will match *only* the elements that are even children of a parent *AND* who have the `.info_row` class.

Comment: @TylerH this is the answer, thank you.

Comment: @TylerH: Ironically, :nth-child() is as straightforward as it can possibly get - it's authors that read too much into it and overcomplicate it as a result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the `:nth-child()` selector, whereas you should be using the `:nth-of-type()` selector:

```css
.info_row:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: orange
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <div class="info_row">
    <div>Category:</div>
    <div>data</div>
  </div>
  <div class="info_row">
    <div>Category 2:</div>
    <div>data</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Explanation

The `:nth-of-type()` selector selects the **n-th child of a parent element that corresponds to the specific type** (i.e. a `div` tag). On the other hand, the `:nth-child()` selector select the **n-th child of a parent element, regardless of type**, thus counting the `h2` element, too.

Comment: Your explanation is correct, but your assumption of what OP wants appears to be incorrect.

Comment: @TylerH Updated, this should be the proper solution that OP wants.

Comment: Your original explanation was correct, the one you've now added is incorrect...

Comment: @BoltClock I'm pretty confused right now, as I am reading the OP's question over and over. Does he/she not want to have the even `.info_row` elements colored orange? I would really like to update my answer to the right one, which I clearly can do, but the whole question explaining has got me confused right now. Also, the answer was marked accepted after the last edit...

Comment: The "type" in :nth-of-type() does not refer to "the rest of the selector". The "type" refers to the tag name.

Comment: Aha, @BoltClock, I see what you mean, I will take a second to update this. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

What You are selecting is the nth-child of the same element so you can 
give it a space like that `.info_row :nth-child(even)` which means the nth of its children  or add the child div like that `.info_row >div:nth-child(even)`

```css
.info_row >div:nth-child(even) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <div class="info_row">
    <div>Category:</div>
    <div>data</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This :

```css
.info_row div:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <div class="info_row">
    <div>Category:</div>
    <div>data</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**OR**

```css
.info_row div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <div class="info_row">
    <div>Category:</div>
    <div>data</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

.class:nth-child(x) doesn't mean "select the number x between the .class elements", it means "select all the .class elements which are the number x of its parent".

For example, `div:first-child` will not select the div in:

```
<p>foo</p>
<div>bar</div>
```